# how to add lines to source code at compiling but keeping it intact

Tags: awk, extern

I want to compile source codes but I need to add extern "C" to a lot of header files from other package. So I have to keep those intact at the same time.
What I am wondering is, can I add

```
#ifdef __cplusplus  
extern "C" {  
#endif
```

at the header and

```
#ifdef __cplusplus  
}  
#endif
```

to the footer for every header I am interested in?
What I can think of is passing those files to the compiler using `$awk` but I cannot come up with the details.
Is there any known examples or something I can dig in?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can create wrappers instead that include the headers in question like this:

```
extern "C" {
#include "header.h"
}
```

In your own code, you then include the wrappers, not the original headers.

You can automate the creation of those wrapper headers with a one-time script, which should be straightforward. In Bash, for example, I'd just do something like:

```sh
for f in include/*; do echo -e "extern \"C\" {\n#include \""$f"\"\n}" > "include_wrappers/wrap_$f"; done
```

Comment: I had to use  `for f in include/*;do awk 'BEGIN{print "#ifdef __cplusplus \nextern \"C\" {\n#endif\n"}{print}END{print "#ifdef __cplusplus\n}\n#endif" }' "include/$(basename $f)" > "include_wrappers/$(basename $f)";done` because I thought that the problem might lie in the header files not directly included by my code but brought in by the header file I used. So I add headers and footers to all header files, but it still doesn't compile. I guess I have to consider if g++ with extern "C" really gives the same environment as gcc. Thank you tho.

Comment: @WJin It looks to me you've generated files with the same name. How can you be sure the new files are getting included rather than the old ones?

Comment: The compiler searches the include directory in the same order I list directories in -I option.